# jquery screensize adjust on sizing screen

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate

having a little trouble right now.. http://www.pizziehere.com  .. as you can see the logo animates down and the bigger logo in the middle slides up on page load.. problem I am having right now.. when you adjust the screen size.. my media queries for smaller screens looks out of wack.. but if you refresh it at a smaller screen size it's fine..

heres my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
        $('.logobig').animate({'padding-top': '100px'}, 1000);
        $('.logo').animate({'padding-top': '150px'}, 1000); 
    }
});
```

how can i make it so when the screen is resized everything stays where it needs to stay?

thanks

Comment: Have you looked into .resize()? http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: yes but unsure on how to apply it to my code..

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).resize(function($){
    //do your logic here
});
```

Comment: what exactly would I be putting in "//do your logic here"?

Comment: have you tried using percentages instead of pixels? Maybe you can use jQuery(document).resize(function($){
    $('.logobig').css({'padding-top': $(window).width()*.1+'px'}
});

Comment: was going to go with percentages but instead went with 3 separate media queries.. wasn't intending on throwing this animation on it.. but now that its their i like it but not the whole resizing thing